# Is there a technique in how to write certain expression in certain times of integration as in case of $\int \frac {(3x + 2)} {(5x + 1)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, improper-integrals

[image: Integration solve]

I can solve this integration $$\frac{3} {5}\int\frac{1}{5x + 1}dx + \frac{7} {5}\int\frac{1}{(5x + 1)^2}dx$$ but thing is I dont under how that online calculator wrote $$3x + 2$$ as $$\frac{3}{5}(5x + 1) + \frac{7}{5}$$
I have difficulty understanding that step. I know we have to make numerator and denominator same but is there a method to not guess that I have to multiply by 3/5 and add 7/5 but a standard way of doing some mathematical magic and getting a value that makes it easy to change $3x + 2$ to $\frac{3}{5}(5x + 1) + \frac{7}{5}$

Comment: They are basically doing [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).

Comment: oh the wiki seems hard to understand; reading it rn

Comment: For the particular example you state, $3x+2=3(x+\frac 23)=\frac 35(5x+\frac{10}3)=\frac 35(5x+1+\frac 73)$

Comment: thanks for pointing out topic; i will read about partial fraction decomposition, and would you writing this coment as answer or will deleting question will be better?

Comment: Deleting a question is never "better", unless it is spam or isolated PSQ-posts. I suggest writing an answer of your own to make sure you really understand it. And maybe, while you're at it, work out similar examples. And if you find it working, mark the answer as accepted, so that any reader who visits this page in the future may find it helpful. :)

Comment: ok I may write answer tomorrow, i need to understand it for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just partial fraction decomposition. The key step is to write $3x + 2 = A(5x + 1) + B$, as you want the $5x+1$ terms to cancel so you can integrate $\frac{A}{5x+1} + \frac{B}{(5x+1)^2}$, which can be done by $u$-substitution.

Comparing coefficients will be easier than substituting $x = -\frac{2}{3}, -\frac{1}{5}$ (remember, this should be an identity that holds for all $x$). Thus $3x + 2 = 5Ax + (A + B)$, or $3 = 5A \implies A = \frac{5}{3}$ and $2 = A + B \implies B = \frac{1}{3}$. And now you can integrate.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get at such things is to use a substitution.  Let $u= 5x +1$ in your example, then $x=(u-1)/5$ and your integrand goes like this:

$$\frac{3x+2}{(5x+1)^2} = \frac{ 3\left(\frac{u-1}{5}\right)+2}{u^2} = \frac{ \frac{3}{5}u - \frac{3}{5}+2}{u^2} = \frac{ \frac{3}{5}u+\frac{7}{5}}{u^2}. $$

Now put $5x+1$ back in for $u$.

You want to express the numerator in terms of the denominator, so make the denominator just one variable.

Comment: Also I am not sure when should u should be equal to 5x + 1 and not 3x + 2, is there a chart or link on what to let u as  @B. Goddard

Comment: The goal is to make the more complicated part simpler.  $3x+2$ is just a linear function.  The $1/(5x+1)^2$ part has squaring and reciprocating.  So if I use $u=5x+1$ it makes the complicated part $1/u^2$.   That's about the only rule of thumb I can think of.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help, I understand both method clearly now